# Configuration data broken after upgrading to Magento from 2.2.5 to Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3.3, magento-upgrade, core-config-data

i Have 3 multi websites , with each websites have 3 different store views, After upgrading to Magento 2.3.3 from 2.2.5 , i've encountered some issue:

1. Magento 2.3.3 prints empty base URL, so all the link generated in my site becomes `index.php/xxx`
2. My configuration data in store configuration is empty
3. My theme configuration is empty, logo, header, etc is gone, when i set the theme, it still shows no theme after i saved the theme configuration and the logo still not uploaded

When i look up at the `core_config_data` all the data is there, but there are seems an increasing amount of records

Magento 2.2.5 `core_config_data` for `theme_id`
[image]

Magento 2.3.3 `core_config_data` for `theme_id`
[image]

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: check the scope values of the `core_config_data` it may happen . It may have like `default`, `stores`,`websites`

Comment: From upgrading magento2.2.5 to 2 3.3 you need to first upgrade magento 2.2.5 to 2 2.8 and then upgrade magento 2.2.8 to 2.3.3

Comment: @MageSoftech yes there seems to be increasing in core_config_data records

Comment: @rahulChittora why i need to do that?